# PYTHON trip_cost('Pittsburgh', 4) raised an error: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found

Tags: python, unicode

I don't see where I messed up. I just started Python 2 days ago and this is from a Codecademy problem.

**Error**

`trip_cost('Pittsburgh', 4) raised an error: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found`

**Code**

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    else:
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
        cost = cost - 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost = cost - 20
    return cost

def trip_cost(city, days):
    city = raw_input("What city are you travelling to?")
    days = raw_input("How many days are you staying?")
    total_cost = hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days)
    print total_cost
```

Answer (score 2):

`trip_cost()` ignores the arguments passed to it. The calls to `raw_input()` within it return strings (in Python 2.x), but your other functions expect integers to be passed to them. Use the `input()` function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    else:
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
        cost = cost - 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost = cost - 20
    return cost

def trip_cost(city, days):
    city = raw_input("What city are you travelling to?")
    days = raw_input("How many days are you staying?")
    total_cost = hotel_cost(int(days)) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(int(days))
    print total_cost

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trip_cost(None, None)
```

To explain a bit:
`raw_input` will give you a string.
If you're going to do arithmetic operations on the value you get from raw_input, you need to cast it as an integer.

Also, if you're trying to run this from the command line, you'll need the bottom two lines.

Really you should replace:

`def trip_cost(city, days)`

with

`def trip_cost()`

because you're not populating the city and days values from parameters passed into the method, but rather getting those values from the console with the raw_input.

If you do that, then change:

`trip_cost(None, None)`

to

`trip_cost()`

So with all of that said, this is how I would ultimately rewrite it:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    else:
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = days * 40
    if days >= 7:
        cost = cost - 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost = cost - 20
    return cost

def trip_cost():
    city = raw_input("What city are you travelling to?")
    days = raw_input("How many days are you staying?")
    total_cost = hotel_cost(int(days)) + plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(int(days))
    print total_cost

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trip_cost()
```

And the output looks like:

```
(cost)macbook:cost joeyoung$ python cost.py 
What city are you travelling to?Pittsburgh
How many days are you staying?4
922
```